# How to reload environment variables file in a running Docker container

Tags: environment-variables, docker

I have a running container with an environment variables file mounted as such:

`docker run -d --env-file ./env.list my/image` and everything is working well, now I have updated my `./env.list` file and would like the updated files to be reflected. Tried restarting the container but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It's currently not possible. Check [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3285) and [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2733).

See if using `docker commit` to [save](https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#committing-saving-a-container-state) the state and create a new instance will fit your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the references, pretty helpful. Unfortunately the only way is to re-run the container for now.